# How Amazon CloudSearch determines instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

From AWS CloudSearch FAQ:

> CloudSearch is a fully managed search service that automatically
>   scales your search domain and selects the number and type of search
>   instances. All search instances in a given search domain are of the
>   same type and this type can change over time as your data or traffic
>   grows. It is not possible to choose the search instance type or the
>   number of search instances directly.

I tried the AWS calculator by trying out few values, and the change to different instance type happens exactly at a particular no. of documents & size in KB combination:

- 1001448 @ 1KB each => Small instance
- 1001449 to 4418157 @ 1KB each = > Large instance
- 4418158 to ... => Extra Large instance

Is this a reliable measure to plan my app, or is better info available anywhere else?